# Progress bar doesn't showing while deleting records in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, progress-bar

I would like to remove the selected records from Kendo Grid datasource after confirmation and show progress bar while deleting records.

For the confirmation, I am using the Kendo Dialog box and a progress bar for showing loader. I am executing below code on the event of "Yes" button from the confirmation. Everything is working fine, but the progress bar doesn't appear on screen, but when I do debug it is showing. I don't know how to figure it out.

I am using Jquery kendo UI.

Code delete action :

```
    kendo.ui.progress($("#divDialog").data("kendoDialog").element, true);
    //close the progress bar
    var dsLineItem = $("#grdLineItem").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    var data = dsLineItem.view();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].IsDeleted) {
            dsLineItem .remove(data[i]);
        }
    }
    kendo.ui.progress($("#divDialog").data("kendoDialog").element, false);
```

Code of dialog constructed :

```
$("#divDialog").kendoDialog({
    visible: false,
    title: "Confiramtion",
    modal: true,       
    show: function onShow(e) {
        var buttons = $('.k-dialog button.k-button');
        $(buttons).eq(0).focus();
    },
    close: function () {
        this.destroy();
    },
    content: "Are you sure want to delete ?",
    actions: function(){
        // I have do code here for deletion
    }
});
$("#divDialog").data("kendoDialog").open();
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the non-debug running is so fast the run-time interval is less than the progress bar animation duration, or some other internal progress bar timer. In other words, the bar is getting closed before it can display.

You might want to also code an auto-closing REMOVAL DONE dialog, such as:

```
    var alert = kendo.alert("Records removed.");
    setTimeout (function () { alert.close() }, 5000); * auto-close alert after 5 seconds;
```

Also depending on the CRUD methods, you might be asynchronously queueing up the removals.  In such a case the queueing finishes (and progress bar closes) before the actual removals -- the progress bar could be managed by the grids dataSource change event handler(s)

Comment: No, its not like. I have tried setTimout and process to take much time to delete records but unfortunately no luck.

Comment: Can you show how the kendoDialg of `divDialog` is constructed ?

Comment: Can you construct a Dojo that shows it not working ?  The progress animation appears in this dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/eDiBuGuL , Do the actions you code also closing the dialog, or is the user supposed to explicitly close the dialog themselves ?

Comment: It is working but doesn't work in my scenario. I will do code and will you show.